# Android floating view on top of any android application

Tags: android, view, floating

How to make floating bubble,like in copy bubble app? That floats on top of every android application, and when cliicked shows another view. Like that orange bubble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple example for floting bubble example: [Floating Bubble](https://github.com/koduribalaji/FloatingExample)
 customize this as your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using WindowManager In Android.

By Using Window Manager you can add the views. On top of any android application.
The Following link may useful to you.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.view.WindowManager